# Error: unrecognized selector but my outlets seem to be correct

Tags: swift

I am getting the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController didTapButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fac8e719530'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

However, I have connected my button to an IBAction and it appears correct in the story board.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let retrieveData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "tasks")
    
    tasks = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Task].self, from: retrieveData!)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  
  //  titleField.delegate = self
   // altTextField.delegate = self
   // hoursField.delegate = self
   // minutesField.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = UIImagePickerController()
    vc.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    vc.delegate = self
    //vc.allowsEditing = true
    present(vc, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]as? UIImage {
        //taskImage.image = image
        print("image selected: ")
        print(image)
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkdv1.png)

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pULZ5.png)

How do I fix this error?

Comment: The error message tells you the problem. `'-[UIViewController didTapButton:]` means you did not set this view controller in the storyboard as the correct view controller subclass. Thus this message is being sent to a plain vanilla UIViewController, which of course has no `didTapButton` method.

Comment: check your story board